# Trying to forward multiple emails with one Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to forward several verified email addresses with one lambda function or do I need to create a lambda function for each verified email I would like to forward? If possible, how would I change the Python code? Would it be to something like this?

def create_message(file_dict):

```
sender = os.environ['VerifiedAddress1@example.com']
recipient = os.environ['ExampleRecipient1@gmail.com']

separator = ";"
```

def create_message(file_dict):

```
sender = os.environ['VerifiedAddress2@example.com']
recipient = os.environ['ExampleRecipient2@yahoo.com']

separator = ";"
```

def create_message(file_dict):

```
sender = os.environ['VerifiedAddress3@example.com']
recipient = os.environ['ExampleRecipient3@gmail.com']

separator = ";"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda will let you do whatever you want within the time, memory and size limits. You can send as many emails as you want as long as you don't go above those limits or hit another external limit (eg: API limits).

I don't understand your python code. Are you trying to create 3 different methods? You can do this by creating just 1 method and passing the sender and recepient as parameters to these methods.

```
separator = ";"
def create_message(file_dict, sender, recepient):
    # Your Email logic goes here


create_message({}, os.environ['VerifiedAddress1@example.com'], os.environ['ExampleRecipient1@gmail.com'])
create_message({}, os.environ['VerifiedAddress2@example.com'], os.environ['ExampleRecipient2@gmail.com'])
create_message({}, os.environ['VerifiedAddress3@example.com'], os.environ['ExampleRecipient3@gmail.com'])
```